# Google Font Not Rendering In Chrome v50

Tags: google-chrome, google-webfonts

Could use some help on this one. I've spent hours trying all the suggestions on this site with no luck. Tried the suggested webkit body font styles. I've tried changing the path from https to just // for the font link. I've tried the suggested javascript codes. I've tried adding !important to my font style. No luck with any of them :-/

BACKROUND:

- Fonts render fine in IE 11
- Using Open Sans font family
- This is on an intranet
- This is a very old site I was just assigned to update... the code is OLD lol. It's an XSL file. No body tag is being used so that might be what's negating the webkit suggestion. I have global font styles applied to html
- NOTE: I'm not redoing the XML (there's a lot of database connectivity I don't have the time to play with), I'm just redoing the UI. Doing tableless CSS design. So coding other than the HTML/CSS may be wonky (site was originally designed in 2002).
- There's an ASP page that pulls in this XSL page. The XSL page is where all of the HTML/CSS lives

CSS (PARTIAL):

```
html { 
    font: 300 16px #333 "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
}

body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#myInfoBox {
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 406px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:auto;
background-color: #ECF7FD;
}

.myInfoBoxLabels {
    width: 250px;
float: left;
text-align: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 40px;
vertical-align: bottom;
display: inline-block;
}

.myInfoBoxData {
    width: 116px;
padding: 0 0 0 5px;
float: right;
    text-align: left;
margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

XSL INFO (PARTIAL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
<!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
<!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
<!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
<!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;"> 
<!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
<!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
<!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:param name="iad" select="'default value'" />
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=" " />
<xsl:template match="/"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<xsl:for-each  select="myPortalFeed[strIAD=$iad]" >  
<div id="outerBorder">
<div id="headerContent"><img src="assets/Header.jpg" width="983" height="138" alt=""/></div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div class="title">2016 Info for <strong>XXXXX PLACEHOLDER NAME (IAD)</strong></div>
    <div>XXXXX PLACEHOLDER COMPANY</div>
    <div class="weekOf">Week XXX of XXX</div>        
    <div id="myInfoBox">
        <div class="myInfoBoxLabels">Status</div>
        <div class="myInfoBoxData">XXXXX</div>
        <div class="myInfoBoxLabels">Point Totaldiv>
        <div class="myInfoBoxData">XXXXX</div>
    </div>

    <div id="creditsBoxHeaders">
        <div class="creditsBoxColHeaderSpacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="creditsBoxColHeader">Silver<br/>Conference</div>
        <div class="creditsBoxColHeader">Gold<br/>Conference</div>
        <div class="creditsBoxColHeader">Platinum<br/> Conference</div>
        <div id="floatMe"></div>
    </div>
```